# How to add an existing variation to a product

Tags: commerce

How to add an existing variation to a product?
When I create a product the form forces me to create a new variation, but I also want to add an existing one to the same product.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some background information.  Otherwise, your question runs the risk of being closed.

Comment: Thank you. Drupal commerce kickstart 2.32. when i am creating a new product display  i also have to create a new variation of the product. I would like to know if i can add an existing variation. not to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I know what you're talking about Nikolaos, and you're in luck! There's a checkbox!

Here's an animated gif that walks you through the steps that I've outlined below:

[image: Change IEF to Add Existing Products]

1. Navigate to your Content Types
2. Manage Fields on your Product Display (you may have more than one of these)
3. Locate the Product Reference or Product Variations Field, click "Edit"
4. Scroll to the middle and locate the checkbox "Allow users to add existing variations"
5. ...
6. Profit!